# WebSite address from Strings

Tags: java, android

I don't know why i can't build url from Strings, I want to send some variable with GET method.
For example i want to send current time to server, and i doing this that:

Thiscur method gets rent time from Android Device:

```
public String getCurrentTimeInString() {
    Time currentTime = new Time();
    currentTime.setToNow();
    String ret = currentTime.format("%k:%M:%S");
    return ret;
}
```

And I create url with this method:

```
String url = "mySite.com/index.php?var1=value&var2=" + getCurrentTimeInString() + "&var3=value";
```

To connect to serwer I use HttpClient, HttpGet and I have error when I doing this that, but why ? I think the problem is in the getCurrentTimeInString method becouse when I create String h = "55" and I replace the getCurrentTimeInString() with h it's working, but why ? What is bad in this method ?

Comment: What exact error do you get?

Comment: I have solution, the problem was in first char in ret String, that was white char (" "), but this is correctly ? currentTime.format("%k:%M:%S") in normal situation return white char in first element ?

Comment: I had a hard time trying to understand your question. smh

Comment: Meybe becouse my english is not very good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `man strftime` for format options of `Time.format` ([javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html#format%28java.lang.String%29) links there) you can notice that it says:

" %k     The hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number (range 0 to 23); **single digits are preceded by a blank**.  (See also %H.)  (TZ)".

So you can use `%H` option to avoid spaces and get leading 0s. Url's can't contain spaces and usually URL encoders replace spaces with `%20` character or `+`.

Comment: But when the time is for example: 10:30:20, first char isn't blank/white char, it's only '1' ? First char is blank when the hour is under ten ?

Comment: yes, option `%k` uses fixed width and prepends blanks to single digit values. Option `%H` prepends 0s instead.

Comment: If you don't like to use `%H` because of leading 0s you can call format 2-3 times with `format("%k")`, etc for example, trim results and then concatenate them.

Comment: ok, if I use option %H I will get 0 in first char when the hour is under ten, and this solution is very good.

Comment: Please accept this answer if it answers your question so that other people would not spend their time trying to answer it ;)